# how to handle a large number of ajax requests

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, performance, ashx

I have a lot of GUIDs(400 maybe more) and I need to use those to query a database and get a status.  However I don't know if the status will be set yet(another application waits for the 'jobs' to be inserted then runs them and updates the row with the status of that job).  But I do know it will be set fairly soon.  I have to use AJAX requests to get all the data.  What would be some effective ways of accomplishing this?  SO far I have a collection and whenever the GUID attribute is set on the model it starts polling the database by making ajax requests every 3 seconds.  This works but its is slow and I am worried I am flooding the network with too many ajax requests.

I am using jquery.ajax to send the data to an ashx handler that calls a stored procedure.

Comment: if you're in control of the service, then mod it so you can accept batch orders. e.g. instead of sending one-guid-per-request, send over multiple guids in ONE request. the minor extra processing required to build the list of guids to send over will be utterly MINOR compared to the huge overhead of doing one http request per guid.

Comment: take it a **look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)** and see some tutorials on YouTube for example, then all you need to do is register your client in groups (that would be the collection of ids) and signalR will continue pooling and show data on client without you handle ajax requests manually!

Comment: OK, this was my initial thought the problem is that I don't know which ones have a status yet or not.  So if i send 400 GUID I might only get back 10 with an actual status. I'll clarify a little more in my question as to why.

Comment: Polling can be dangers. Do you have to update every 3 seconds? How about 10 seconds? 30? You could store your GUIDs in session so the poll request is lighter. How often do the GUIDs change? How many concurrent users do you expect?

Comment: It sounds like you have 400 guids and each is asking for a status individually? You could just do all in one request/response, if that is acceptable. Or you could send all in a request and poll for updates as they complete until all statues are recieved.

Comment: I dont have to update its like this each guid represents a task to be completed my app places the job info in the database.  Another application I also wrote process that info then updates thats row with the appropriate status.  So I have no idea when that will happen.  Once I figure the status out its over for that particular guid, no updating.

Comment: And will they be the same guids on every poll? If so, maybe you can send them to the server and just wait. Or you can let the server return a batch ID, and then poll the state of that ID each second (or longer. The server can just return all GUIDs that received a status since the previous poll.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid active polling, the best alternative are WebSockets.
Unfortunately, it is a new technology and it cannot be used by some browsers(IE9-). [here](http://caniuse.com/websockets) you can see if it is enough covered for you and you can use any polyfills for major browsers, as IE8-9, which at the end, will be using active polling, but, at least, your poll requests will be decreased.

Take a look in google for more info and good luck!